# Terminal dinámica en NeoVim

Tags: linux, terminal, neovim

Tengo un Error `EOFError` el ejecutar sctipt de Python, la terminal de `NeoVim` no captura la funcion `input()`, puedo hacer la terminal dinamica?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Probe el Plug de floaterm pero esta deprecado
- Probe hacerdo funcionar con `:term`
- Probe con `try:`, `except:` y no funciono